# How do I separate a string by one of the separators but not by all of them?

Tags: python, regex, string, validation, split

```
She is Mary.  Ella es Maria.
She is Mary."    Ella es Maria."
She is Mary." Ella es Maria."
Hello!.     Hola!.
Hello.!     Hola.!
Hello!     Hola!
How are you?.    Como estas?.
How are you?    Como estas?
```

How to use one of these as a separator, testing if it can split the string with one of them, and if it can split with one of them then stop testing with the rest
`.!`, `.?`, `."` , `?"` , `?.` , `?` , `!"` , `!.` , `!` , `."` or(not and)  `.`

```py
match = line.split(".",1)
n_sense = match[1].strip()

print(n_sense)
```

Is there a way to test whether or not I can split it with a conditional? Or should I use regex?

If this works fine `print(n_sense)` should print at the end:

```
Ella es Maria.
Ella es Maria."
Ella es Maria."
Hola!.
Hola.!
Hola!
Como estas?.
Como estas?
```

Comment: It looks to me like you should be splitting on "2 or more spaces" and then `strip` the results.

Comment: The problem I'm sensing is the case where there are endings like this  `.!`, `.?`, `."` , and in those cases it cuts on the point, but not on the sign immediately after it, and in those cases it cuts at the point, but not at the sign immediately after it, so it breaks the string badly, for example: `!     Hola.!`  . That's why I say that the order in which the algorithm tries to use `split()` is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

tests = [
    "She is Mary.  Ella es Maria.",
    'She is Mary."    Ella es Maria."',
    "Hello!.     Hola!.",
    "Hello.!     Hola.!",
    "Hello!     Hola!",
    "How are you?.    Como estas?.",
    "How are you?    Como estas?",
]

for test in tests:
    x = re.split(r'[.!?][.!?"]?\s+', test)[1]
    print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Ella es Maria.
Ella es Maria."
Hola!.
Hola.!
Hola!
Como estas?.
Como estas?
```

Comment: Really thanks for the help